# URL rewriting in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url, url-rewriting

i have a web site which will navigate to a different domain once logged in.
I need to re write the url by removing the aspx page of the URL and add the domain name from which it navigates to.Also i want to rewrite the URL in an https page which will be redirected from a http page.
for eg:-from the site www.xyz.com it has been redirected to www.abc.com.so the url should be displayed as www.abc.com/xyz
can anyone can help me on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL rewrite in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620169/url-rewrite-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

This is commonly done in ASP.NET MVC and this is called [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx). This is applieable in ASP.NET WebForms as well.

You can also use an IIS Module called [IIS Rewrite](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/), this is somewhat like Apaches mod_rewrite if you know how that works.

[Here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/) is a tutorial on how you get it working.

From MSDN regarding ASP.NET Routing:

> In a Web Forms application, you create
>   routes by using the
>   MapPageRoute(String, String, String)
>   method of the RouteCollection class.
>   The MapPageRoute method creates a
>   Route object and adds it to the
>   RouteCollection object. You specify
>   properties for the Route object in
>   parameters that you pass to the
>   MapPageRoute method.
>
> Typically, you add routes in a method
>   that is called from the handler for
>   the Application_Start event in the
>   Global.asax file. This approach makes
>   sure that the routes are available
>   when the application starts. It also
>   enables you to call the method
>   directly when you unit-test the
>   application. If you want to call a
>   method directly when you unit-test the
>   application, the method that registers
>   the routes must be static (Shared in
>   Visual Basic) and must have a
>   RouteCollection parameter.
>
> The following example shows code from
>   a Global.asax file that adds a Route
>   object that defines two URL parameters
>   named action and categoryName. URLs
>   that have the specified pattern are
>   directed to the physical page named
>   Categories.aspx.

This is your Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "Category/{action}/{categoryName}",
        "~/categoriespage.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use URL rewrite module for that. Some examples are here:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/